# The best way to combine two m4v files on Catalina

Tags: software-recommendation, catalina, video, encoding, macos

I've seen [Best way to merge mp4 files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/best-way-to-merge-mp4-files) and I've seen similar articles such as https://www.adeepbite.com/combine-videos-mac-using-quicktime-player/

I have a computer with OSX Catalina. I've got some 3+hr recordings from 2-DVDs that should be a single length file, and transferred them to two m4v files using Handbrake, using these settings:

[image: This is a screenshot of Handbrake showing the settings I am using. Preset: Fast 1080p30, Format: MP4 File, not web optimized, with Align A/V Start, no iPod 5G support, and then it lists several internal options that I don't quite claim to understand fully]

Because those articles and questions are over 4 years old, and the state of the art has likely improved, I'm curious if there are better solutions to the problem of "combine two m4v files". I'm also curious if I've transferred them to my computer at a sub-optimal configuration in Handbrake for the media that I am trying to put together.

What if I needed to remove the first, say, 10 seconds from the second file as well before I join them, does that change the tools needed?

I believe my best choices are https://www.mp4joiner.org/en/, QuickTime Player, and QuickTime Pro, yes? I would like to focus this question not on "what programs can also do this" but "what is the best native or near-native solution to joining two files?"

<sub>I recognize that shopping list questions are off topic and really don't have a place here, as the technology does change too quickly, so if this is off-topic as well, I understand.</sub>

<sub>If the other question that I've linked is still the best option to combine two M4V files, then I'll gladly accept a close-as-dupe</sub>

Comment: *Because those articles and questions are over 4 years old...*  Did you attempt the solutions presented?  Just because something is old doesn't mean it's no longer viable and that it hasn't kept up with technological advancements. The computer mouse was initially released in 1968 and we *still* use it in the same way even with all of the technological advancements since then.

Comment: When was the hammer invented - still basically the same...

Comment: Not that they aren't still viable processes, I'm just curious if there's a newer option. I don't live and breathe by the breakneck development world, but that also means I don't know when new things have come out. Once upon a time I didn't know about ssh either. Hammers are great, but nailguns are better. My grandfather's wooden handle hammer is nice, but my Estwing is a lot nicer for long days of building things. Sometimes new things do show up you know. I've done the QT thing a couple times before but it "felt wrong" for some reason.

Comment: @Allan the accepted answer on the duplicate question says to use Quicktime Pro, and [On September 24, 2018 Apple ended support for QuickTime 7 and QuickTime Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime#QuickTime_Pro). Seems like a valid reason to get an updated answer.

Comment: @Josh - accepted doesn't mean it's the *only* answer; it's the answer the OP accepted.  There are countless questions where the accepted answer isn't the highest voted.  I refer you back to my computer mouse example.

Comment: Thanks. I'm very familiar with how Stack Exchange works, I've been using it for over 10 years. In this case all the answers on that question are outdated and sub-optimal. I'll write my own answer on that other question and suggest that the OP here propose an edit modernizing the question.